# Overscroll effect in gallery class android?

Tags: android, gallery

How to implement overscroll effect in gallery class android?

```
setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);
```

I try to override

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) 
{
    System.out.printf("onOverScrolled\n");
}
```

but no output

Comment: can you share your answer

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.printf()` does nothing on Android, I believe. To output something like that, use `Log.i()` and look in Eclipse in the DDMS view. I personally use `Log.e()` because it isn't constantly being printed to like i and d, but since it's not technically an error, it's bad form.

Comment: You are wrong. System.out.printf() is working.I use this method in other methods and it work.

Comment: Question is not "why i dont see".Question is "Why overscroll dont work".

Comment: Oh, it is? I didn't know that worked. `setOverScrollMode()` is only available in API level 9 and up (Gingerbread). What device are you testing on?

Comment: Try forcing the gallery to overscroll manually with `overScrollBy()`. If it doesn't work, I don't know of any way to make it work. There are quite a few other questions almost identical to this on SO; I would try looking there to see if this question has ever been resolved.

Comment: From docs-"Scroll the view with standard behavior for scrolling beyond the normal content boundaries. Views that call this method 
 should override onOverScrolled(int, int, boolean, boolean) to respond to the results of an over-scroll operation." It is not good.

Comment: Huh. It seems like the `setOverScrollMode()` on a `ScrollView` doesn't work either, so I guess you'll have to use a normal, not overscrolly Gallery.